# Can I resolve fields that are not in the model with @GraphQLQuery

Tags: java, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

We are using graphql-spqr to generate the graphql schema from our Java backend api and model.

Today to get products for example we annotate a methods that looks like that:

```
@GraphQLQuery
List<Product> allProducts() {...}
```

We want to avoid creating a new endpoint to retrieve extra fields in Product.

**Is there a way to define a resolver for fields that are not part of the model?** (annotation or not)

As an example, let's assume our java model for a Product + two end points:

```
class Product {
   String id;
   String name;
}

class Frame {
  String id;
}

// and some kind of relationship between the two
class ProductToFrame {
  String productId;
  String frameId
}

List<Product> allProducts();
List<Frame> getFramesByProductId(String productId);
```

And we want our graphql schema to look like that:

```
type Product {
  id: String
  name: String

  frames: [Frame] 
}

type Frame {
  id: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is something like this (e.g. next to your existing `allProducts()` method:

```
@GraphQLQuery
public List<Frame> frames(@GraphQLContext Product product) {
    return getFramesByProductId(product.getId());
}
```

The `frames` field will then be attached to its *contextual* `Product` type. Or in other words: the `Product` type will get an extra field called `frames`, as desired.

Make sure you look through the tests in SPQR. They act as a showcase for most features.